# React Native Navigation: cant click in navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-native-module

I'm trying to use react navigation. But when I click on the button to navigate, nothing happens. I'm new to React Native.

App.js:

```
function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();


  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

HomeScreen.js

```
  function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>HomeScreen Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Detail"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

DetailScreen.js:

```
function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

When I click in "GO TO DETAIL" nothings happends
[image: Navigation]

What can be the problem?

**EDIT:
I think that the problem could be from the emulator, maybe I dont "click" correctly on the button**

Comment: It's working for me, are you sure you imported the right things?
`import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'` and `import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'`

Comment: export the functions if they are on another file

Answer (score 0):

Using react-native 0.69 and emulator Pixel 4 API 33, same happened. The solution for me.

- Close your app in the emulator: In my case, square button and swipe up the app.
- Open again and try clicks!
- Thumbup is it work

Answer (score 0):

Button works as intended in the code so I would recommend:

1. Close your metro instance and then your emulator
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm run android` or `npm run ios` in case you work with ios.